# find the greatest area of a parallelogram of two vertices lie on $x/a+y/b=1$ and the other two vertices lie on the two axes

Tags: geometry, optimization, area

find the greatest area of a parallelogram of two vertices lie on $x/a+y/b=1$ and the other two vertices lie on the two axes

[image]

Comment: Do you know calculus? Are $a,b$ fixed and positive? What have you tried?

Comment: i was trying to get y in terms of x and i get y=b/a (a-x)

Comment: If you allow any position of two points on the axes the area can be infinitely large.

Comment: Presumably it's implied they should lie on the positive axes

Comment: @CadeReinberger It is not sufficient. Obviously it is assumed that they lie on the segments shown in figure, but the problem does not mention this.

Comment: I don't get I acutely solve copple of questions like this but on a rectangle but I don't know why I can't solve it on a parallelogram

Comment: You may assume that the parallelogram is a rectangle. This does not matter.

Comment: ca you solve it for me I don't  get it

Comment: Max area is $\frac{\left| a b\right| }{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(ka,0)$ and $B(0,kb)$ be the vertices, where $0<k<1$.

By Pythagoras' theorem, the base is $AB=k\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and the height is $\dfrac{ab(1-k)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Can you proceed with that?

Comment: i will try this now

Answer (score 0):

this should be the solution
If you have any question we can discuss in the comments

tou can find the complete formula of d online (distance of a point from a line)

[image]

Comment: no thanks I was doing it wrong I get it now thans